# python unknow urltype valuError image in file downloading

Tags: python

I am trying to download a massive image, and most of the urls are blank and error type.

When I run the script, it downloads the image but when it see wrong URL type, the script stope. I want it so that the script doesn't stop when it sees wrong url or blank url, so that is skip the wrong url and go to next url.

Here is the example of wrong urls and code:

```
import wget

urls = ['https://www.1000-annonces.com/appartement-a-louer-a-cote-hotel-solazur-IMGH1552740173_img20190316wa00061.jpg',
       'https://www.1000-annonces.com/proche-ouarzazate-vends-kasbah-maison-d-hotes-IMGH1376736359_piscine__chauffee.jpg',
       'badurl.jpeeg'
       'https://www.1000-annonces.com/bel-appartement-en-bord-de-mer-IMGH1541404860_img20180826wa0065.jpg',
       'https://www.1000-annonces.com/appartement-a-louer-a-cote-hotel-solazur-IMGH1552740173_img20190316wa00061.jpg',
       ]

for url in urls:
    wget.download(url)
```

You may suggest to clean URLs or remove wrong, however I don't want to do this. This is because my script will find url and then request for download, no way to clean the url to remove wrong url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a `try` and `except` block like below. This will try to download the image from your urls and if it is not able to, then it will continue as if nothing happened.

```
import wget
import urllib

urls = ['https://www.1000-annonces.com/appartement-a-louer-a-cote-hotel-solazur-IMGH1552740173_img20190316wa00061.jpg',
       'https://www.1000-annonces.com/proche-ouarzazate-vends-kasbah-maison-d-hotes-IMGH1376736359_piscine__chauffee.jpg',
       'badurl.jpeeg'
       'https://www.1000-annonces.com/bel-appartement-en-bord-de-mer-IMGH1541404860_img20180826wa0065.jpg',
       'https://www.1000-annonces.com/appartement-a-louer-a-cote-hotel-solazur-IMGH1552740173_img20190316wa00061.jpg',
       ]

for url in urls:
    try:
        wget.download(url)
    except urllib.error.URLError:
        continue
```

Comment: The continue cant be used for loop? I am webscraping, when a image come to the script, it will script, i wasnt used for loop and that is why i cant use contine. is the any way to use without for loop?

Comment: @mamuncode why can't you use a for loop? This downloads all of the images that have valid URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Exception Handling is what you're looking for. Use try and except blocks. The control flow goes like this, whenever there is an exception raised in the try block the control immediately goes to the except block. So the modification in your code would be

```
import wget
import urllib

urls = ['https://www.1000-annonces.com/appartement-a-louer-a-cote-hotel-solazur-IMGH1552740173_img20190316wa00061.jpg',
       'https://www.1000-annonces.com/proche-ouarzazate-vends-kasbah-maison-d-hotes-IMGH1376736359_piscine__chauffee.jpg',
       'badurl.jpeeg'
       'https://www.1000-annonces.com/bel-appartement-en-bord-de-mer-IMGH1541404860_img20180826wa0065.jpg',
       'https://www.1000-annonces.com/appartement-a-louer-a-cote-hotel-solazur-IMGH1552740173_img20190316wa00061.jpg',
       ]

for url in urls:
    try:
        wget.download(url)
    except urllib.error.URLError:
        pass // exception handling code goes here
```